# If I have g++ 5.1.0 version installed on my computer, can I use g++-4.7 command to compile?

Tags: c++, makefile

My g++ version:

```
g++ (GCC) 5.1.0
```

I tried to compiler another person's code, in his makefile:

```
CXX := g++-4.7 -std=gnu++0x
```

So when I `make` the files, it said

```
make: g++-4.7: Command not found
```

So is there any way that I can make the version 5.1.0 compatible to the previous version? Or do I need to install another version of g++ on my computer to make the Makefile work?

Comment: The simplest way would be to edit the `Makefile`, replacing `g++-4.7` with `g++`  or perhaps `g++-5`

Comment: If this is a one-time hack, you can create a symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/g++-4.7` to gcc 5.

Comment: Better also replace `-std=gnu++0x`  with `-std=gnu++11`

Answer (score 0):

You need to find where your g++-4.7 is located using `which` command.

```
ML> which g++-4.7
/usr/local/bin/g++-4.7
```

Then you can give the full path for CXX. The compiler option of `-std=gnu++0x` should be in `CFLAGS`.

```
CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-4.7 
CFLAGS+=-std=gnu++0x
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no problem with having multiple versions of any compiler on your system.

Important is, that also the required libraries located where the compiler expect them. It is important that your compilation and linking comes from exactly ONE compiler tree. The compiler is not a stand alone program, it depends on the libraries it links to for your program build.

My advice is:
Install every compiler version you want from sources of gcc. Don't forget to build also binutils for each version in the correct path.

My installation as example is something like:

```
/opt/linux_gnu_4.6.4
/opt/linux_gnu_4.9.2
/opt/power_pc_4.8.1
```

and so on.

You simply create each version with proper installation path if you do the
`configure/make/make install` for gcc and binutils with exact same path settings which is named `prefix`

For that you have to:

```
./configure --target=avr --prefix=/opt/avr_4.8.2
```

as an example. This is needed for binutils AND gcc in the SAME way! For gcc you can compile with additional `--enable-labuages=c,c++` to reduce compile time if you don't need other languages and libraries.

After that you can give in your Makefile

```
CC = /opt/avr_4.8.2/bin/avr-g++
```

So you can have any version for any target in parallel.

There is/was also an option to build gcc for multiple targets. But I have never tried that.

If you install the gcc from your distro you will get in trouble, because typically the directory which was configured in with `--prefix=<some dir>` is for all versions the same which makes it impossible to get clean and separated file hierarchy for all the versions and libraries.